# I am trying to make two columns, but the second won't position correctly

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Here is the CSS I used to make the columns

```
<style>
        h1{background-color:black;
            color: white;
        }
        .columnA{f
            float: left;
            width: 70%;
            margin:0;
        }
        .columnB{
            float: right;
            width:30%;
            margin: 0;

        }
        div.clear{clear:both;}


    </style>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="columnA">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
        <div class="columnB">

                Test 1<br>
                Test 2

        </div>
    </div>
```

It ends up looking like the second div won't move up. I've tried float: left too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error.. Change `f float` to float in `.columnA`

```css
.columnA{
    f float: left;
    width: 70%;
    margin:0;
}
```

should be

```css
.columnA{
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mupau/)

This was your [original code](http://jsfiddle.net/Mupau/1/)

Comment: well that's embarrassing. Thanks for being that second pair of eyes! I felt so silly that it wasn't working!

Comment: Thats fine. CSS is tricky at times :) If this was useful, please do accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your css you have an extraneous `f`

```
.columnA{f
    float: left;
```